# How to display results based only on the part of the date in sql query in access

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

At the moment my query displays records based on the range for 2016 - and presents results in Monthly view `(Jan, Feb, March, Apr..)`

```
SELECT Reference.source_ID AS Source, 
Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between #1/1/2016# And #12/31/2016#,1,0)) AS Total, 
Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between #1/1/2016# And #1/31/2016#,1,0)) AS Jan, 
Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between #2/1/2016# And #2/29/2016#,1,0)) AS Feb, 
Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between #3/1/2016# And #3/31/2016#,1,0)) AS Mar, 
Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between #4/1/2016# And #4/30/2016#,1,0)) AS Apr, 
Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between #5/1/2016# And #5/31/2016#,1,0)) AS May, 
Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between #6/1/2016# And #6/30/2016#,1,0)) AS June, 
Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between #7/1/2016# And #7/31/2016#,1,0)) AS July, 
Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between #8/1/2016# And #8/31/2016#,1,0)) AS Aug, 
Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between #9/1/2016# And #9/30/2016#,1,0)) AS Sept, 
Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between #10/1/2016# And #10/31/2016#,1,0)) AS Oct, 
Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between #11/1/2016# And #11/30/2016#,1,0)) AS Nov, 
Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between #12/1/2016# And #12/31/2016#,1,0)) AS [Dec]
FROM Reference
GROUP BY Reference.source_ID;
```

I wish to add search form that would allow user select a date range

This would add the following parameters to my query

```
WHERE (((Reference.quote_date) Between [Forms]![Total_Calls_by_Source_Search]![StartDateTxt] And [Forms]![Total_Calls_by_Source_Search]![EndDatetxt]))
```

My question is how to change the query so it can display results for 2017, 2018, and so on

Comment: you could use the `year([forms]![formname]![field])` function in your where clause which would give you results for the year of that specific date field

Comment: @LiamH how would i go around year specified-in the clause: Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between #1/1/2016# And #1/31/2016#,1,0)) AS Jan

Answer (score 1):

This should group all records by year of `quote_date`, and output the correct count for each month of that particular year, as filtered by the form inputs. Wasn't quite sure what to do with the total line, it's adding 1 for each non-null record in that year. I'm not sure if it works with the GROUP BY refID.

```
SELECT Reference.source_ID AS Source, 
Sum(IIf(ISNULL([quote_date]),0,1)) AS Total, 
Sum(IIf(Month([quote_date])=1,1,0)) AS Jan, 
Sum(IIf(Month([quote_date])=2,1,0)) AS Feb, 
Sum(IIf(Month([quote_date])=3,1,0)) AS Mar, 
Sum(IIf(Month([quote_date])=4,1,0)) AS Apr, 
Sum(IIf(Month([quote_date])=5,1,0)) AS May, 
Sum(IIf(Month([quote_date])=6,1,0)) AS June, 
Sum(IIf(Month([quote_date])=7,1,0)) AS July, 
Sum(IIf(Month([quote_date])=8,1,0)) AS Aug, 
Sum(IIf(Month([quote_date])=9,1,0)) AS Sept, 
Sum(IIf(Month([quote_date])=10,1,0)) AS Oct, 
Sum(IIf(Month([quote_date])=11,1,0)) AS Nov, 
Sum(IIf(Month([quote_date])=12,1,0)) AS Dec
FROM Reference
WHERE (((Reference.quote_date) Between [Forms]![Total_Calls_by_Source_Search]![StartDateTxt] 
  And [Forms]![Total_Calls_by_Source_Search]![EndDatetxt]))
GROUP BY Reference.source_ID, YEAR([quote_date]);
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response @Christoper D.

Answer (score 0):

You can use year as a parameter:

```
Sum(IIf([quote_date] Between DateSerial([year],2,1) And DateSerial([year],2+1,0),1,0)) AS Feb,
```

and likewise for the other 11 months.